# How to dependent match on a list with two elements?

Tags: coq

I'm trying to understand dependent types and dependent match in Coq, I have the code below, at the bottom I have the `add_pair` function, the idea is that I want to receive a (dependent) list with exactly two elements and return the sum of the two elements in the list. Since the size of the list is encoded in the type, I should be able to define it as a total function, but I got an error saying that the `match` is not `exaustive`

Here is the code

```
Module IList.
  Section Lists.
    (* o tipo generico dos elementos da lista *)
    Variable A : Set.

    (* data type da lista, recebe um nat que é
       o tamanho da lista *)
    Inductive t : nat -> Set :=
    | nil : t 0                 (* lista vazia, n = 0 *)
    | cons : forall (n : nat), A -> t n -> t (S n). (* cons de uma lista 
                                              n = n + 1 *)
    (* concatena duas listas, n = n1 + n2 *)
    Fixpoint concat n1 (ls1 : t n1) n2 (ls2 : t n2) : t (n1 + n2) :=
      match ls1 in (t n1) return (t (n1 + n2)) with
      | nil => ls2
      | cons x ls1' => cons x (concat ls1' ls2)
      end.

    (* computar o tamanho da lista é O(1) *)
    Definition length n (l : t n) : nat := n.
  End Lists.
  Arguments nil {_}.

  (* Isso aqui serve pra introduzir notações pra gente poder
     falar [1;2;3] em vez de (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))) *)
  Module Notations.
    Notation "a :: b" := (cons a b) (right associativity, at level 60) : list_scope.
    Notation "[ ]" := nil : list_scope.
    Notation "[ x ]" := (cons x nil) : list_scope.
    Notation "[ x ; y ; .. ; z ]" := (cons x (cons y .. (cons z nil) ..)) : list_scope.
    Open Scope list_scope.
  End Notations.
  Import Notations.

  (* Error: Non exhaustive pattern-matching: no clause found for pattern [_] *)
  Definition add_pair (l : t nat 2) : nat :=
    match l in (t _ 2) return nat with
    | (cons x (cons y nil)) => x + y
    end.

End IList.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is true that the match you provided is exhaustive, but the pattern-matching algorithm of Coq is limited, and not able to detect it. The issue, I think, is that it compiles a nested pattern-matching such as yours (you have two imbricated `cons`) down to a successions of elementary pattern-matching (which have patterns of depth at most one). But in the `cons` branch of the outer `match`, the information that the index should be `1` is lost if you do not record it explicitly with an equality – something the current algorithm is not smart enough to do.

As a possible solution that avoids fiddling with impossible branches, equalities, and the like, I propose the following:

```coq
  Definition head {A n} (l : t A (S n)) : A :=
    match l with
    | cons x _ => x
    end.

  Definition tail {A n} (l : t A (S n)) : t A n :=
    match l with
      | cons _ l' => l'
    end.

  Definition add_pair (l : t nat 2) : nat :=
    head l + (head (tail l)).
```

---

For the record, a solution that *does* fiddle with the impossible branches and records the information of the index using equalities
(there’s probably a nicer version):

```coq
  Definition add_pair (l : t nat 2) : nat :=
    match l in (t _ m) return (m = 2) -> nat with
      | [] => fun e => ltac:(lia)
      | x :: l' => fun e =>
        match l' in (t _ m') return (m' = 1) -> nat with
        | [] => fun e' => ltac:(lia)
        | x' :: l'' => fun e' =>
          match l'' in (t _ m'') return (m'' = 0) -> nat with
          | [] => fun _ => x + x'
          | _ => fun e'' => ltac:(lia)
          end ltac:(lia)
        end ltac:(lia)
    end eq_refl.
```

The interesting part is the use of explicit equalities to record the value of the index (these are used by the `lia` tactic to discard impossible branches).

Comment: Thank Meven, how can I record the index in an equality so it's not lost in the branch, can you provide an example?

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to add that. Beware, it burns!

Comment: Thank you, this is so cool! I didn't know that you can discard impossible branches using ltac and never saw this `ltac:...`, thank you so much!

Comment: The `ltac:(lia)` after `end` are the application of the `fun e => ...` functions returned by the match?

Comment: Yes! They are used to generate the right equalities from the one available in context. For instance the lowest one constructs a proof of `m = 1` from the proof of `S m = 2` available in context (`e`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation Meven, I'm looking into sig and passing proofs around seems terrible, I hope I can learn such trick soon